# iPhone iOS how to serialize / save UIColor to JSON File?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, uicolor

When I need to save a color to core data, I simply use NSKeyedArchiever and then unarchieve color when I need to load the entity. However, when I try to serialize the core data entity, the process fails because it does not know how to convert the keyed archiever's NSData to a string.

What's the best way to convert a UIColor to a string representation for sending within JSON file? One solution is to store the r,g,b,a values as floats. One solution is to save it as a hex string. Both of these seem to complicate the process of color restoration

Am I missing something ? Is there an easier way to serialize a UIColor within JSON?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about that:

```
NSDictionary *colorData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.f], @"Red",
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:24.f], @"Green",
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:23.f], @"Blue",
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.f], @"Alpha", nil];

NSDictionary *color = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:colorData forKey:@"Color"];
```

The result is something like:

```
{"Color":{"Green":24,"Alpha":1,"Blue":23,"Red":100}}
```

You can easily make a method that takes `UIColor` as an argument and return a NSDictionary, that can be serialized directly. The reverse process is the same.

Comment: What if color is created from a pattern image?

Comment: Then you only save the path of the image.

Answer (score 3):

Solution I found is to create CIColor from the UIColor then convert back:

Convert to string:

```
CIColor(color: UIColor.blue).stringRepresentation
```

Convert to color:

```
UIColor(ciColor: CIColor(string: databaseColorString))
```

Comment: The simplest solution 

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no defined standard for putting a `UIColor` (let alone a generic "colour") in JSON you are going to have to roll your own.

I would suggest that the nicest method would be to have a category on `UIColor` that gives you the standard hex code for the colour in RGB colour-space and also takes in such a hex code and spits out s `UIColor`. Then transmit that hex code in the JSON.

I know it might seem like overkill, but it's by far the most portable and compact solution.

An example of the hex to `UIColor` method can be found in my [MJGFoundation `UIColor` category](https://github.com/mattjgalloway/MJGFoundation/blob/master/Source/Categories/UIColor/UIColor-MJGAdditions.m). A similar one to go from `UIColor` to hex value wouldn't be too hard to write but be aware of having to get it in RGBA colour-space first.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the freedom of having a "private" format for the colors. Some colors do not react well to being asked for RGBA (hence why the `get...` methods return a `BOOL` -- they don't always succeed), so this implementation includes the color type as well as the values.

```
@implementation UIColor (JSON)

- (NSString *)json_stringValue
{
    CGFloat r, g, b, a, h, s, w;
    if ([self getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a]) 
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rgba:%f,%f,%f,%f", r,g,b,a];
    else if ([self getHue:&h saturation:&s brightness:&b alpha:&a])
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hsba:%f,%f,%f,%f", h,s,b,a];
    else if ([self getWhite:&w alpha:&a]) 
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"wa:%f,%f", w, a];

    NSLog(@"WARNING: unable to serialize color %@", self);
    return nil;
}

@end

@implementation NSString (JSON)

- (UIColor *)json_color
{
    NSArray *comps = [self componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
    NSArray *colors = [comps[1] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSUInteger count = colors.count;
    CGFloat values[4] = {0,0,0,0};
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) values[i] = [colors[i] floatValue];

    if ([comps[0] isEqualToString:@"rgba"]) 
        return [UIColor colorWithRed:values[0] green:values[1] blue:values[2] alpha:values[3]];
    else if ([comps[0] isEqualToString:@"hsba"])
        return [UIColor colorWithHue:values[0] saturation:values[1] brightness:values[2] alpha:values[3]];
    else if ([comps[0] isEqualToString:@"wa"])
        return [UIColor colorWithWhite:values[0] alpha:values[1]];

    NSLog(@"WARNING: unable to deserialize color %@", self);
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the two answers results in the following:

To save:

```
#import "UIColor-HSVAdditions.h"
#import "JSONKit.h"

UIColor* color = textView.textColor;
            NSDictionary *colorData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:color.hue], @"Hue",
                                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:color.saturation], @"Saturation",
                                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:color.brightness], @"Brightness",
                                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:color.alpha], @"Alpha", nil];

            NSString* jsonString = [colorData JSONString];
```

To load:

```
 NSDictionary* dictionary = [coreDataEntity.fontColor objectFromJSONString];

                    NSNumber* hue =[dictionary objectForKey:kHueKey];
                    NSNumber* saturation =[dictionary objectForKey:kSaturationKey];
                    NSNumber* brightness =[dictionary objectForKey:kBrightnessKey];
                    NSNumber* alpha =[dictionary objectForKey:kAlphaKey];

                    UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue.floatValue saturation:saturation.floatValue brightness:brightness.floatValue alpha:alpha.floatValue];

                    textView.textColor = color;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Swift Package to help with this!

```swift
import SerializationTools

let exampleColor = UIColor.systemRed

let colorJsonString = try exampleColor.codable.jsonString()
// This ends up being a Base64 UTF-8 string representing the `NSCoding` representation

let recreatedColor = try UIColor.CodableBridge(jsonString: colorJsonString).value
```

And this retains the fancy magical colors like `.label` and `.systemBackground`!

You can get it here: https://github.com/RougeWare/Swift-SerializationTools